# What's up!? (------ puzzle)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the phrase I'm looking for?**

---

[image]

---

**Note:** The specific colors I've chosen is not important.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase you're looking for is:

> **ASTROLOGICAL SIGNS**

To solve, first recognise that what we have here is:

> an inwardly spiralling trail beginning at the red '1' space, passing through blue, then dark red, dark grey, yellow, cyan, etc. There are twelve sets of colours, and if we enter one letter in each it is possible to enter the names of the **twelve signs of the Zodiac** into this spiral, preserving the order of the signs like so:
>
>  [image: Spiralling boxes filled in with letters to spell Zodiac signs]

Now all that remains is to:

> read off the letters indicated by numbers in that numerical order. This spells out the phrase **ASTROLOGICAL SIGNS** (which suggests to me that the missing six-letter word in the title - which conjures up the idea of looking *up* at the stars - is '**Zodiac**'...).

The diagram reproduced as text:

> **A(1)**-ries
>  tauru-**S(2)**
>  **G(8)**-emini
>  **C(10)**-ancer
>  **L(6)**-eo
>  vi-**R(4)**-go
>  **L(12)**-ibr-**A(11)**
>  scorpi-**O(7)**
>  sa-**G(15)**-i-**T(3)**-tar-**I(14)**-us
>  capric-**O(5)**-r-**N(16)**
>  aquar-**I(9)**-us
>  pi-**S(13)**-ce-**S(17)**

Comment: Everything good. And yes, that was my intention with the title. Well done!

Comment: Congrats for achieving 100k! And of course you solved this puzzle within 1 hour :P

Comment: What tips you off that the theme is astrology? You just tried various categories which have 12 members?

Comment: @justhalf It was the fact there were 12 colours (so my mind immediately goes to months, star signs, Chinese zodiac, birthstones...) and the word lengths (notably shortest is 3 and longest is 11). Pub quiz trivia comes in handy here :)